# Freeswitch reporting hook

Tags: python, freeswitch

Is it possible to execute a python script at the end of each call, so it could access `billsec` variable and send them to my API? There is `session.setHangupHook` method, but if i try to get `billsec` variable there, it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`billsec`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/billsec) is not available until the handlers have exited and the call is disconnected. Instead, use [`api_hangup_hook`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/api_hangup_hook) which is invoked after the call is complete.

```
<action application="set" data="session_in_hangup_hook=true"/>
<action application="set" data="api_hangup_hook=python script.py ${uuid}"/>
```

More info: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/api_hangup_hook